# Unitary representation of dilatations in Minkowski space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Consider a field theory in Minkowski space (Lorentzian signature). I'm looking at the Dilatation operator $D$ which presumably satisfies:

$$[D,\phi(0)]=\tilde{\Delta}\phi(0)$$

where $\phi(0)$ is a Hermitian operator located at the origin of space-time. If $D$ is Hermitian then $\tilde{\Delta}$ must be real: if $|d\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $D$ with eigenvalue $d$ then

$$D \phi(0)|d\rangle = (\tilde{\Delta}+d) \phi(0) |d \rangle$$

so $\tilde{\Delta}+d$ is an eigenvalue of $D$ and $\tilde{\Delta}$ must be real. But then I get that exponentiating the dilatation operator gives me

$$e^{i D \lambda} \phi(0) e^{-i D\lambda} = e^{i \tilde{\Delta}\lambda} \phi(0)\,.$$

I was under the impression that if $U(\lambda)$ generates dilatations we want it to satisfy

$$U(\lambda) \phi(0) U^{-1}(\lambda) = e^{\Delta \lambda} \phi(0)\,.$$

My conclusion would then be that the latter definition of dilatations is a non unitary transformation. Is this correct? I have never seen this discussed in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

In Minkowski signature $D$ is anti-Hermitian. Indeed, consider a real scalar $\phi$, then we have
$$
[D,\phi(x)]=(x\cdot \partial_x+\Delta_\phi)\,\phi(x)
$$
where the right-hand side is a Hermitian operator. Therefore, we should have a Hermitian operator on the left, which is only possible when $D$ is anti-Hermitian. I.e.
$$
[D,\phi]^\dagger=[\phi^\dagger,D^\dagger]=-[D^\dagger,\phi].
$$
This solves your problem because the finite unitary rescaling is then $e^{\lambda D}$.

However, this leads to an apparent contradiction: the state
$$
|\psi\rangle = \phi(0)|0\rangle
$$
is an eigenstate with of $D$ with real eigenvalue $\Delta_\phi$, even though the operator is anti-Hermitian, which would suggest pure imaginary eigenvalues. The resolution is that the way one proves the latter is by considering the expectation value of $D$ in $|\psi\rangle $. This doesn't work in this situation because $|\psi\rangle $ is not normalizable,
$$
\langle\psi|\psi\rangle =\langle 0|\phi(0)\phi(0)|0\rangle=undefined.
$$

In fact, the Hermitian operator which has the discrete spectrum of eigenvalues equal to operator dimensions in Minkowski signature is not $D$ but the so-called conformal Hamiltonian $H=P^0+K^0$. To see this, note that this operator corresponds to the vector field
$$
v_\mu=-\delta^0_\mu+2x_\mu x^0-x^2\delta^0_\mu.
$$
The points $x^\mu=(\pm i,0,0,\ldots)$ are fixed by this vector field. Thus this operator satisfies
$$
[H,\phi(-i,0,0,\ldots)]\propto \Delta_\phi\phi(-i,0,0,\ldots),
$$
where the constant of proportionality is real. Note that the state
$$
|\phi\rangle\equiv \phi(-i,0,0,\ldots)|0\rangle=e^{-P^0}\phi(0)|0\rangle
$$
is well-defined, because $P^0$ is energy and thus bounded from below, and thus has finite norm
$$
\langle\phi|\phi\rangle=\langle 0|\phi(i,0,0,\ldots)\phi(-i,0,0,\ldots)|0\rangle < \infty.
$$
Therefore, it gives a well-defined eigenstate of $P^0+K^0$.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the first part of your answer is essentially a replacement $D \to iD$ which is fine, but doesn't make the problem go away. Regarding the second part, I am strictly interested in quantizing the theory such that the Hamiltonian moves me along surfaces of constant Minkowski time. In other words, I want the Hamiltonian to be $P^0$ and not the combination $P^0+K^0$. Is that not possible?

Comment: @OtherPerson, no, I'm not replacing $D$ by $iD$ -- then $i$ would appear in the commutation relations, but it doesn't. I'm saying $D$ in your question is anti-Hermitian, even though scaling dimensions are real.

Comment: @OtherPerson, of course you can quantize in this way. I was just pointing out the operator which has the  "expected" discrete spectrum. $P^0$ has a continuous spectrum, as you would expect in a scale-invariant theory. The operator-state correspondence also holds, regardless of what you take your Hamiltonian to be.

Comment: I think that if I add an 'i' in the commutation relations then all is well. For example, you seem to use $[D,P^{\mu}]=P^{\mu}$ with $P^{\mu}$ Hermitian whereas others would use the same equation with an $i$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Also, I was under the impression that the state-operator correspondence works only in radial quantization. There we insist that reflection positivity act in a way that makes the theory on a sphere (times a line) unitary. But this does not mean that the theory on Minkowski space will be unitary.

Comment: @OtherPerson, I am talking about $[D,\phi(0)]=\Delta_\phi \phi(0)$. If you read my answer carefully, you will see that real $\Delta_\phi$ is only consistent with _anti-Hermitian_ $D$. In fact, if you consider non-zero $x$, i.e. $[D,\phi(x)]=(x\cdot \partial_x+\Delta_\phi) \phi(x)$, you can see that reality of $\Delta_\phi$ is also required. This cannot be fixed by adding $i$ anywhere, I am talking about exactly the $D$ from your question. Because it is _anti-Hermitian_, $e^{i\lambda D}$ is not the unitary you are looking for, $e^{\lambda D}$ is, solving your problem.

Comment: @OtherPerson, the Hilbert space is the same in radial and the usual Minkowski quantization (more precisely, they are isomorphic by a conformal transformation which turns unit sphere into a plane). In the latter case the statement of operator-state correspondence is that states of the form $\int d^d x f(x) \mathcal{O}(x)|0\rangle$ for all local primaries $\mathcal{O}$ span a dense subspace of the Hilbert space. Here $f(x)$ is a Schwartz test function. Alternatively, you can use states $\partial^n\mathcal{O}(-i,0,0,\ldots)|0\rangle$, which also have finite norms as discussed in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69564/discussion-between-other-person-and-peter-kravchuk).